# jQuery jCapSlide implementation on multiple dynamic images

Tags: jquery, umbraco

I've found this cool jQuery plugin jCapSlide that displays an image caption when you hover over the image, by sliding up an overlay div.

The problem is, I can't find any documentation for it, and the few instructions i did find about it say that I have to target the elements by ID, but in my case that's not possible because I'm generating images dynamically with no guarantee how many there will be. This is what I have done so far: (I am using Umbraco CMS, and images are created with a Razor macro).

```
var products = Model.AncestorOrSelf(1).Descendants("Product").Where("Visible").Items;

foreach (var product in products)
{
if (product.favourite == true)
{
    <div class="floatProducts">
    <div class="outerSqrProducts">
    <div class="sqrProductsImage">
        <a href="@product.Url">
            <img src="@product.Media("mainImage","umbracoFile")" alt="@product.Media("mainImage","altText")" />
        </a>
        <div class="overlay" style="display:none;"></div>
        <div class="ic_caption" style="display:none;">
            <h2>@product.Name</h2>  
        </div>  
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
}
}
```

In the head of my template I have this...

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.sqrProductsImage').capslide({
                    caption_color    :   '#FFFFFF',
                    caption_bgcolor  :   'rgb(0,148,217)',
                    overlay_bgcolor  :   'rgb(0,148,217)',
                    border           :   '',
                    showcaption      :   false

            });
        });
    </script>
```

I have all the js and css files included in the head as well but nothing is happening.  Can anyone offer any suggestions?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an Umbraco question!

You don't provide any reference to the script itself that you are using so all we can do is guess on the implementation however my suggestion would be, if you have to use an ID then simply iterate over all elements with a particular class and grab the id - seems pretty inefficient though!

Untested example to demonstrate what I mean:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var elements = $('.sqrProductsImage');
    $.each(elements, function() {
            $($(this).att("id")).capslide({
                caption_color    :   '#FFFFFF',
                caption_bgcolor  :   'rgb(0,148,217)',
                overlay_bgcolor  :   'rgb(0,148,217)',
                border           :   '',
                showcaption      :   false
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Reference: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: Thanks for your response ProNotion.  I tagged it with umbraco because i it is important that I explain that I am generating these imaages dynamically.  I've since tried writing my own script to achieve the same thing, which works for one image but not on multiple.  I've tried your approach but it didn't work I'm afraid.

Comment: Didn't work in what way? Can you provide some more detail or better still put together an example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). You also need to make sure that all of your .sqrProductsImage elements have id's which they do not in your example.

Comment: I was just doing that now.  Have a look at this. http://jsfiddle.net/JohnHalsey/aFG9k/9/

Comment: I tried with the $($(this).att("id")) as in your post, but that didn't work so I took out some of it to see if made any difference.

Comment: I've worked it out. Gave the main div a dynamic id, then just found the other divs within it. http://jsfiddle.net/JohnHalsey/aFG9k/10/

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out by doing this in the end.  Wrote my own jQuery script.

HTML:

```
<body>

    <div class="outerSqrProducts">
        <div class="sqrProductsImage">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="http://www.avenir-accessories.co.uk/media/4367/beewi-fiat-500-white.jpg"/>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <div class="ic_caption" id="caption1">
            <h2 class="centerText">Title</h2>   
         </div>
    </div>

    <!-- this could be repeated x amount of times in the dynamic code -->
    <div class="outerSqrProducts">
       <div class="sqrProductsImage"> <a href="#">
        <img src="http://www.avenir-accessories.co.uk/media/4367/beewi-fiat-500-white.jpg"/>
        </a>


        </div>
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <div class="ic_caption">
                <h2 class="centerText">Title</h2>   
        </div>
    </div>

    <body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #0097F0;
}
.centerText {
    text-align: center;
}
.outerSqrProducts
{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 234px;
    width: 234px;
    background-color: #FFF; 
    position: relative;

}
.sqrProductsImage 
{
    display: inline-block;
}
.sqrProductsImage img {
    max-height: 234px;
    max-width: 234px;
}
.overlay, .ic_caption {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
}
.overlay {
    background-color: rgba(0, 151, 240, 0.5);
    height: 100%;
}
.ic_caption {
    background-color: rgba(0, 151, 240, 0.8);
    height: 50%;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var div = $('.outerSqrProducts');
    var overlay = $('.overlay');
    var title = $('.ic_caption');
    var speed = 500;

    div.each(function (i) {
        $(this).attr('id', 'image' + i);
        var divId = $(this).attr('id');

        $('#' + divId).hover(function () {
            // make background opaque
            $('#' + divId).find('.overlay').fadeIn(speed);
            // slide down the title
            $('#' + divId).find('.ic_caption').slideDown(speed);
        },

        function () {
            $('#' + divId).find('.ic_caption').slideUp(speed);
            $('#' + divId).find('.overlay').fadeOut(speed);

        });
    });

});
```

Works like a charm.